# PHP Object Can't Call Function Inside If Statements

Tags: php

please point out the obvious as I just started learning about OOP in PHP. My class `books` contains two public functions: one to display a request books form, and the other to submit the book details to my database. I use two `if` statements to call these functions when the user clicks the `request book` or `submit form` buttons.

Here is my class:

```
class Book
{
    public $title;
    public $author;
    public $id;

    public function SendToDatabase()
    {
        echo "inside SendToDatabase";
    }

    public function Display()
    {
        echo "<form action='' method='post'>
    Title: <input type='text' name='title'><br>
    Author: <input type='text' name='author'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submitBook' value='submit'>
    </form>";
    }

}
```

And here is my code to call the functions using buttons (in the same file). As is, the `SendToDatabase()` function is never called. I am able to get it working when I combine the `if` statements, but then the buttons would not work properly. I am a little confused because I thought the scope of the object is the same across if statements. I would really appreciate anyone pointing out my mistake. Cheers.

```
echo "<form action='' method='post'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Request Book'></form>";
$request = $_POST['submit'];
$submit  = $_POST['submitBook'];
if ($request) {
    $book = new Book();
    $book->Display();
}

if ($submit) {
    $book->SendToDatabase();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define what `$book` is in *both* cases, so get the assignment out of the first `if` block:

```
$book = new Book();
if ($request) $book->Display();
if ($submit) $book->SendToDatabase();
```